# Multi-View Spectral Clustering on nested directories of dataframes and multivariate labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, sparse-matrix

The code performs supervised multi-view spectral clustering on a nested dictionary of datasets. The `y` variable is label-encoded and has >1 column by design.The ultimate goal is to achieve meaningful clustering results considering both the multi-view nature of the data and the available class labels.

The `supervised_multi_view_spectral_clustering function` function takes a nested dictionary and a multivariate `y` label. On the other hand, the `find_optimal_clusters_multi_view`  function determines the optimal number of clusters based on silhouette scores obtained from KMeans clustering. Finally, the code iterates over a nested dictionary `train_data_dict`, extracts binary-labeled data, and applies the multi-view spectral clustering using the previously defined functions with the optimal number of clusters.

The error indicates a `TypeError` in the `spectral_clustering` process. Specifically, it states that the method is trying to use `scipy.linalg.eigh` for a sparse matrix (A) with k >= N (where N is the size of the matrix), and it suggests either using `scipy.linalg.eigh(A.toarray())` or reducing k.

I've already converted the data to sparse matrix but the error persisted. Are there other solutions besides minimizing `k`? My code identified optimal `n_clusters` as 8.

Code:

```
def supervised_multi_view_spectral_clustering(X_views, y, n_clusters, affinity='nearest_neighbors', max_neighbors=10):
    """
    Implementing Supervised Multi-View Spectral Clustering.

    Parameters:
    - X_views: List of feature matrices for each view.
    - y: Target variable (multi-variate dataframe with 2 columns).
    - n_clusters: Number of clusters.
    - affinity: Affinity matrix computation method (e.g., 'nearest_neighbors', 'rbf').
    - max_neighbors: Maximum number of neighbors for nearest_neighbors affinity.

    Returns:
    - labels: Cluster assignments.
    """
    # Check if y is already encoded
    if isinstance(y.iloc[0, 0], str):  # Assuming the first element of the dataframe is a string if not encoded
        # Encode labels if they are not numerical
        label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
        y_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(y.iloc[:, 0])  # Convert to 1D array
    else:
        # Use the provided encoded y directly
        y_encoded = y.iloc[:, 0]  # Convert to 1D array

    # Concatenate feature matrices along axis 1
    X_concatenated = np.hstack(X_views)

    # Calculate the maximum allowed number of neighbors
    max_allowed_neighbors = min(X_concatenated.shape[0] - 1, max_neighbors)

    # Create affinity matrix using concatenated features
    if affinity == 'nearest_neighbors':
        from sklearn.neighbors import kneighbors_graph
        adjacency_matrix = kneighbors_graph(X_concatenated, n_neighbors=max_allowed_neighbors, mode='connectivity', include_self=True)
    elif affinity == 'rbf':
        from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import rbf_kernel
        adjacency_matrix = rbf_kernel(X_concatenated, gamma=0.5)

    # Convert the adjacency matrix to a Laplacian matrix
    laplacian_matrix = np.diag(np.sum(adjacency_matrix, axis=1)) - adjacency_matrix

    # Compute the generalized eigenvalues and eigenvectors
    _, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eigh(laplacian_matrix)

    # Use eigenvectors corresponding to the smallest eigenvalues as features for clustering
    X_cluster = eigenvectors[:, :n_clusters]
    
    # Convert to sparse matrix
    X_cluster_sparse = csr_matrix(X_cluster)

    # Apply spectral clustering on the selected features
    spectral = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=n_clusters, affinity='nearest_neighbors', random_state=42, n_neighbors=max_allowed_neighbors)
    labels = spectral.fit_predict(X_cluster_sparse)

    # Evaluate clustering performance using the ground truth labels (y_encoded)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_encoded.values, labels)
    print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy:.2f}")

    return labels

def find_optimal_clusters_multi_view(mixed_representation_list, max_clusters=10):
    concatenated_data = np.concatenate(mixed_representation_list, axis=0)
    optimal_clusters = 2  # Default to 2 clusters

    if len(concatenated_data) > 1:
        silhouette_scores = []

        for n_clusters in range(2, max_clusters + 1):
            # Use KMeans as an example clustering algorithm
            kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=42)
            labels = kmeans.fit_predict(concatenated_data)

            # Calculate silhouette score
            silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(concatenated_data, labels)
            silhouette_scores.append(silhouette_avg)

        # Find the optimal number of clusters based on the highest silhouette score
        optimal_clusters = np.argmax(silhouette_scores) + 2  # Add 2 to start from n_clusters=2

    return optimal_clusters

for outer_key, outer_value in train_data_dict.items():
    for inner_key, inner_value in outer_value.items():
        
        # Check if the inner value contains binary values (0 or 1)
        if inner_value[1].isin([0, 1]).all().all():
            # Accessing the columns directly from the tuple
            columns = inner_value[1].columns
            
            # Create a new dataframe y by subsetting the columns
            y = inner_value[1][columns]

n_clusters = find_optimal_clusters_multi_view(mixed_representation_all)
total_samples = sum(len(view) for view in mixed_representation_all)

# Multi-View Spectral Clustering       
labels = supervised_multi_view_spectral_clustering(
    X_views=mixed_representation_all,
    y=y,  # Use the multi-variate dataframe directly, assuming that the labels are encoded
    n_clusters=n_clusters,
    affinity='nearest_neighbors',
)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [818], in <cell line: 5>()
      2 total_samples = sum(len(view) for view in mixed_representation_all)
      4 # Multi-View Spectral Clustering       
----> 5 labels = supervised_multi_view_spectral_clustering(
      6     X_views=mixed_representation_all,
      7     y=y,  # Use the multi-variate dataframe directly, assuming that the labels are encoded
      8     n_clusters=n_clusters,
      9     affinity='nearest_neighbors',
     10 )

Input In [813], in supervised_multi_view_spectral_clustering(X_views, y, n_clusters, affinity, max_neighbors)
     50 # Apply spectral clustering on the selected features
     51 spectral = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=n_clusters, affinity='nearest_neighbors', random_state=42, n_neighbors=max_allowed_neighbors)
---> 52 labels = spectral.fit_predict(X_cluster_sparse)
     54 # Evaluate clustering performance using the ground truth labels (y_encoded)
     55 accuracy = accuracy_score(y_encoded.values, labels)

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_spectral.py:657, in SpectralClustering.fit_predict(self, X, y)
    635 def fit_predict(self, X, y=None):
    636     """Perform spectral clustering on `X` and return cluster labels.
    637 
    638     Parameters
   (...)
    655         Cluster labels.
    656     """
--> 657     return super().fit_predict(X, y)

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:736, in ClusterMixin.fit_predict(self, X, y)
    718 """
    719 Perform clustering on `X` and returns cluster labels.
    720 
   (...)
    732     Cluster labels.
    733 """
    734 # non-optimized default implementation; override when a better
    735 # method is possible for a given clustering algorithm
--> 736 self.fit(X)
    737 return self.labels_

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_spectral.py:622, in SpectralClustering.fit(self, X, y)
    617     self.affinity_matrix_ = pairwise_kernels(
    618         X, metric=self.affinity, filter_params=True, **params
    619     )
    621 random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state)
--> 622 self.labels_ = spectral_clustering(
    623     self.affinity_matrix_,
    624     n_clusters=self.n_clusters,
    625     n_components=self.n_components,
    626     eigen_solver=self.eigen_solver,
    627     random_state=random_state,
    628     n_init=self.n_init,
    629     eigen_tol=self.eigen_tol,
    630     assign_labels=self.assign_labels,
    631     verbose=self.verbose,
    632 )
    633 return self

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_spectral.py:300, in spectral_clustering(affinity, n_clusters, n_components, eigen_solver, random_state, n_init, eigen_tol, assign_labels, verbose)
    292 n_components = n_clusters if n_components is None else n_components
    294 # We now obtain the real valued solution matrix to the
    295 # relaxed Ncut problem, solving the eigenvalue problem
    296 # L_sym x = lambda x  and recovering u = D^-1/2 x.
    297 # The first eigenvector is constant only for fully connected graphs
    298 # and should be kept for spectral clustering (drop_first = False)
    299 # See spectral_embedding documentation.
--> 300 maps = spectral_embedding(
    301     affinity,
    302     n_components=n_components,
    303     eigen_solver=eigen_solver,
    304     random_state=random_state,
    305     eigen_tol=eigen_tol,
    306     drop_first=False,
    307 )
    308 if verbose:
    309     print(f"Computing label assignment using {assign_labels}")

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/_spectral_embedding.py:299, in spectral_embedding(adjacency, n_components, eigen_solver, random_state, eigen_tol, norm_laplacian, drop_first)
    297 laplacian *= -1
    298 v0 = _init_arpack_v0(laplacian.shape[0], random_state)
--> 299 _, diffusion_map = eigsh(
    300     laplacian, k=n_components, sigma=1.0, which="LM", tol=eigen_tol, v0=v0
    301 )
    302 embedding = diffusion_map.T[n_components::-1]
    303 if norm_laplacian:
    304     # recover u = D^-1/2 x from the eigenvector output x

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_eigen/arpack/arpack.py:1605, in eigsh(A, k, M, sigma, which, v0, ncv, maxiter, tol, return_eigenvectors, Minv, OPinv, mode)
   1600 warnings.warn("k >= N for N * N square matrix. "
   1601               "Attempting to use scipy.linalg.eigh instead.",
   1602               RuntimeWarning)
   1604 if issparse(A):
-> 1605     raise TypeError("Cannot use scipy.linalg.eigh for sparse A with "
   1606                     "k >= N. Use scipy.linalg.eigh(A.toarray()) or"
   1607                     " reduce k.")
   1608 if isinstance(A, LinearOperator):
   1609     raise TypeError("Cannot use scipy.linalg.eigh for LinearOperator "
   1610                     "A with k >= N.")

TypeError: Cannot use scipy.linalg.eigh for sparse A with k >= N. Use scipy.linalg.eigh(A.toarray()) or reduce k.
```

The mixed input is:

```
mixed_representation_all = [np.array([[ 6.86642242e-01,  2.39899190e-01,  2.80446761e-01,
          4.92809061e-03,  1.59718143e-03,  1.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00],
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  7.29018533e-01,  9.37974120e-01,
          4.89314180e-03, -5.18736779e-05,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00],
        [ 6.84257308e-01,  1.06157485e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          4.92809061e-03,  1.59718143e-03,  0.00000000e+00,
          1.00000000e+00],
        [ 8.02062756e-01,  0.00000000e+00,  1.05181581e+00,
          4.92809061e-03,  1.59718143e-03,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00],
        [ 8.70980417e-01,  4.26542892e-01,  0.00000000e+00,
          5.24792355e-03,  1.66885145e-02,  0.00000000e+00,
          1.00000000e+00]]),
 np.array([[ 0.56334143,  0.12725487,  0.        ,  0.00126975, -0.00361982,
          1.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.00122529,  0.80449583,  0.4132248 ,  0.00126975, -0.00361982,
          0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.89751501,  0.01120635,  0.01214377,  0.00126975, -0.00361982,
          0.        ,  1.        ],
        [ 0.54195638,  0.        ,  0.97001332,  0.00126975, -0.00361982,
          0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.25273296,  1.05415771,  0.18261735,  0.00126975, -0.00361982,
          0.        ,  1.        ]]),
 np.array([[ 0.49491938,  0.42366855,  0.17236239, -0.00474108,  0.00749203,
          1.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.75069972,  0.21481801,  0.64188481,  0.00685369,  0.12949724,
          0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.14428094, -0.00485734,  0.00626871,
          0.        ,  1.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  1.63071685,  0.        , -0.00485734,  0.00626871,
          0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 1.07160251,  0.0059672 ,  0.00777407,  0.01468312,  0.21188189,
          0.        ,  1.        ]]),
 np.array([[ 0.49826464,  0.34304662,  0.66995378, -0.00547502, -0.0052609 ,
          1.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.64281231, -0.0410983 ,  0.07813156,
          0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.21595267,  0.77696496, -0.04587942,  0.09054126,
          0.        ,  1.        ],
        [ 1.31695552,  0.02410867,  0.16601993, -0.00547502, -0.0052609 ,
          0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.05631977,  1.40420381,  0.        , -0.00547502, -0.0052609 ,
          0.        ,  1.        ]]),
 np.array([[ 0.16121424,  0.05911174,  0.43021991,  0.00548451, -0.00472075,
          1.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.95901253,  0.24461581,  0.        ,  0.00548451, -0.00472075,
          0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.88282   ,  0.        ,  0.20180751,  0.00548451, -0.00472075,
          0.        ,  1.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  1.40495373,  0.01201259,  0.00548451, -0.00472075,
          0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.95884672,  0.00548451, -0.00472075,
          0.        ,  1.        ]])]
```

The training dict is:

```
train_data_dict = {
    'transcriptomics': {
        'transcriptomics_df': (
            pd.DataFrame({
                'gene_1': [0.324889, 0.715960, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.392615],
                'gene_2': [0.282243, 0.232156, 0.532265, 1.000000, 0.574217],
                'gene_3': [0.921885, 0.310729, 0.619240, 1.000000, 0.785394],
                'gene_4': [0.408865, 0.498760, 0.192590, 1.000000, 0.000000],
                'gene_5': [0.000000, 0.573144, 1.000000, 0.216677, 0.821214],
                'gene_6': [0.519652, 1.000000, 0.916358, 0.592965, 0.000000],
                'gene_7': [0.905142, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.912722, 0.818003],
                'gene_8': [0.000000, 0.929344, 0.192423, 0.725308, 0.325888],
                'gene_9': [0.757505, 0.493086, 0.243973, 0.133332, 0.000000],
                'gene_10': [0.378347, 0.690365, 0.311958, 0.867666, 1.000000]
            }, index=['sample_8', 'sample_3', 'sample_5', 'sample_4', 'sample_7']),
            pd.DataFrame({
                'survival': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                'immune': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
            }, index=['sample_8', 'sample_3', 'sample_5', 'sample_4', 'sample_7'])
        )
    },
    'epigenomics': {
        'epigenomics_df': (
            pd.DataFrame({
                'methyl_1': [0.648307, 0.403001, 0.767676, 0.047227, 0.000000],
                'methyl_2': [0.000000, 0.494575, 0.359736, 1.000000, 0.130327],
                'methyl_3': [0.317773, 0.847600, 0.705968, 0.000000, 1.000000],
                'methyl_4': [0.261844, 1.000000, 0.272183, 0.000000, 0.703201],
                'methyl_5': [0.178545, 0.455849, 0.045604, 0.034345, 0.553393],
                'methyl_6': [0.466456, 0.252746, 0.138116, 1.000000, 0.116700],
                'methyl_7': [0.953612, 0.581519, 0.000000, 0.754646, 0.818478],
                'methyl_8': [0.210986, 0.509216, 0.349948, 1.000000, 0.180805]
            }, index=['sample_8', 'sample_3', 'sample_5', 'sample_4', 'sample_7']),
            pd.DataFrame({
                'survival': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                'immune': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
            }, index=['sample_8', 'sample_3', 'sample_5', 'sample_4', 'sample_7'])
        ),
        'meth_deconv': (
            pd.DataFrame({
                'meth_cell_type_1': [0.683553, 0.000000, 0.027151, 1.000000, 0.913862],
                'meth_cell_type_2': [0.299173, 0.028041, 0.470113, 0.179501, 1.000000],
                'meth_cell_type_3': [0.952748, 0.706878, 0.796396, 1.000000, 0.000000],
                'meth_cell_type_4': [0.020950, 0.000000, 0.014384, 1.000000, 0.419708],
                'meth_cell_type_5': [0.897815, 0.000000, 0.089535, 0.795399, 0.425495]
            }, index=['sample_8', 'sample_3', 'sample_5', 'sample_4', 'sample_7']),
            pd.DataFrame({
                'survival': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                'immune': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
            }, index=['sample_8', 'sample_3', 'sample_5', 'sample_4', 'sample_7'])
        )
    },
    'proteomics': {
        'proteomics_df': (
            pd.DataFrame({
                'protein_1': [0.640386, 0.995708, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.923793],
                'protein_2': [0.158279, 0.000000, 0.388522, 0.131567, 0.612186],
                'protein_3': [0.127003, 0.077220, 0.000000, 0.489785, 0.066448],
                'protein_4': [0.246877, 0.582296, 0.223085, 0.748195, 0.238219],
                'protein_5': [0.126281, 1.000000, 0.944714, 0.925549, 0.000000]
            }, index=['sample_8', 'sample_3', 'sample_5', 'sample_4', 'sample_7']),
            pd.DataFrame({
                'survival': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                'immune': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
            }, index=['sample_8', 'sample_3', 'sample_5', 'sample_4', 'sample_7'])
        )
    }
}
```